# OmniFocus adds note when capturing reminder

Tags: reminders, ios, omnifocus

I have OmniFocus set up to capture reminders created in Reminders.app on my iPhone 6 running iOS 9. Starting with iOS 9, the following text is added to the task's notes field: "Original task available in the 'Captured by OmniFocus' list in Reminders." This text is unnecessary. In fact, it's annoying, because it adds cruft to OmniFocus. How can I stop OmniFocus from adding this note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Omnifocus Support](https://support.omnigroup.com/collecting-with-siri-in-omnifocus-2/)

> In addition, as of OmniFocus 2.7 (our update for iOS 9) the app now leaves captured reminders in Reminders on a special list. This way, any reminders with extra information unavailable to OmniFocus are still accessible.
>
> A reminder captured under this scheme will have a special blurb of text appended to its note:
>   *"Original task available in the 'Captured by OmniFocus' list in Reminders."*

From the [OmniFocus forums](https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-captured-by-omnifocus-list-causing-problems-on-capture/19361)

> Is there any way to turn off or rename "Captured by OmniFocus" to avoid this confusion?
>
> If you'd rather not deal with the Captured by OmniFocus list at all, and you're sure you won't use the deep links functionality in reminders to be captured, you can revert to the old behavior of deleting captured reminders with a preference URL:
>
> `omnifocus:///change-preference?RemindersCaptureDeletesReminders=1`
>
> Any reminders captured after opening this URL will be deleted out of Reminders entirely, instead of being moved to Captured by OmniFocus. Once you change that setting, you can delete the Captured by OmniFocus list. (If you ever want to use the new way again, reopen the above URL, replacing the 1 with a 0; OmniFocus will recreate the Captured list as necessary.)

Comment: This URL does not prevent OmniFocus from adding a note. It deletes the task from Reminders.app.

Comment: Yes, as it says. It's still not reminders behaviour, it's OmniFocus.

Comment: Nevertheless, this solved it. OmniFocus no longer adds a note.